# How can inheritance change the class signature

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm finding that inheriting from a base class can change the derived class signature according to `inspect.signature`, and I would like to understand how that happens. Specifically, the base class in question is `tensorflow.keras.layers.Layer`:

```
import sys
import inspect
import tensorflow as tf

class Class1(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, my_arg: int):
        pass

class Class2:
    def __init__(self, my_arg: int):
        pass

print("Python version: ", sys.version)
print("Tensorflow version: ", tf.__version__)
print("Class1 signature: ", inspect.signature(Class1))
print("Class2 signature: ", inspect.signature(Class2))
```

Outputs

```
Python version:  3.8.10 (default, Mar 23 2023, 13:10:07)
[GCC 9.3.0]
Tensorflow version:  2.12.0
Class1 signature:  (*args, **kwargs)
Class2 signature:  (my_arg: int)
```

I tried running the code above and I expected it to print the same signature for both classes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are metaclasses in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug behavior that is unique to earlier versions of Python, including 3.8 and early patch releases of Python 3.9/3.10

In 3.8 and 3.9.4:

```
Class1 signature:  (*args, **kwargs)
Class2 signature:  (my_arg: int)
```

In newer versions of Python, like 3.9.17 and latest versions of 3.10 and 3.11, the result is how you would expect:

```
Class1 signature:  (my_arg: int)
Class2 signature:  (my_arg: int)
```

I'm not 100% sure what exactly changed the behavior between these python versions, but my best guess is that this is related to either [this issue](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/85074) or [this issue](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/74044), which were fixed in Python3.11 and backported to some earlier Python versions. However, Python3.8 did not receive any of these backport fixes.

Comment: Yes this is right. I verified that `keras.Layer` does in fact define a `__new__` method, and also that inheriting from a simpler class that only defines a `__new__` method reproduces the issue. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Ah, yes @AndreaAllais -- this issue may have some relevant discussion of the problem (or maybe a related problem): [CPython GH-105080](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/105080)